# Getting browser URL

Tags: flash

I need to get the browser address (url) to a variable in flash (*.swf file)

I tested few codes,

```
 1. var myurl:String = loaderInfo.loaderURL;

 2. var myurl = stage.loaderInfo.parameters["browserURL"];

 3. import flash.external.*;
    var myurl = ExternalInterface.call("window.location.href.toString");
```

But always variable (myurl) gives undefined.

What is the code to get the browser url?

I'm using Macromedia Flash MX 2004

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [LocalConnection](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html) :

```
var lc:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();

var myurl = lc.domain;
```

Comment: Hint: OP uses *Macromedia Flash MX 2004*. And I strongly doubt,that he/she uses *ActionScript 3* compiler.

Comment: It didn't work friend. Output is "[type Function]".                   It gives myurl = [type Function]

Comment: @ErandaGunathilaka let's take some time to report back :)

Comment: @loxxy I said, that the OP uses very old environment for writing and compiling swf files.And may be used actionscript version does not support `LocalConnection` class.

Comment: @Engineer It doesn't & I agreed with you. I just told OP we would be looking for other solutions..